# Codeigniter - Ajax request, finds controller but 404's anyway?

Tags: php, ajax, security, codeigniter-2

I have been working on a project that requires me to make ajax calls to controllers in codeigniter. Locally the site works just fine, but after uploading it to my webhost (Versio) is stopped working.

For some reason it seems like the ajax call finds the controller, but gives me a 404 error anyway. The reason I think it actually finds the controller is because when I change the url the AJAX request is made to it shows me a different 404 page instead of the standard CodeIgniter 404 page.

My request looks like this:

```
var baseURL = "http://sitename.com/index.php/";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseURL+"Encounter/startEncounter",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

My config file looks like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

XSS filtering is on and CSRF is off.

My default controller looks like this, which loads just fine:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "index";
```

My HtAccess file is currently empty.

Thank you very much for your time, hopefully someone can help with with this phroblem. The hundereds of answers I have found before had no result.

Sincerely Yours,
Nick

Comment: What does the Encounter controller startEncounter method look like?

Comment: do you set route $route['Encounter/startEncounter'] ?

Comment: you added `baseURL` to your js code after you uploaded it on the server or before that?

Comment: @Sam Encounter/startEncounter basically just echoes some text, it worked on localhost so the problem shouldn't be inside the controller.

Why would I have to set that route?

Before that, but before it just contained "index.php/"

Comment: then why you add Encounter/startEncounter end of your url in Ajax, i think thats why you get 404page

Comment: What happens when you go to the page ''Encounter/startEncounter' in the browser?

Comment: @asef seferov It's not the route, the route will be done automatically as the controller and method are set up

Comment: @Sam It shows me the codeigniter-style 404 page. And I agree that the route is probably not the problem.

Comment: Change the base url to be $config['base_url'] = ''; and try using the URL without the captial letters

Comment: @Sam Thank you, for some reason it worked. I emptied the config baseURL and set baseURL in JS to 'index.php/'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a header to allow cross origin ajax calls :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

in the `index.php`.

Comment: Sounds like this could potentially create a security issue? Also, I'm not getting an access-control-allow-origin error at the moment.

Comment: Sorry then, but you can obviously control which domain can get the access control and/or add an authentication system. That's how most of mobile apps work since each app has a different ip.